# 401 Error Sending GET users/show to Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am attempted to get user details of a twitter user who has authorized my app by using the GET users/show. I am using raw Java for this, not the Twitter API (hence the lack of documentation). I am able to successfully get a request token, and an access token but I get a 401 error on the last step when I am attempting to get the user info. Does anyone notice what I am doing wrong here?

```
int t = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000);
    String n = generateNonce();
    String parameterStr = "oauth_consumer_key=" + TWITTER_KEY +
                          "&oauth_nonce=" + n +
                          "&oauth_signature_method=" + oauthSignatureMethod +
                          "&oauth_timestamp=" + t +
                          "&oauth_token=" + USER_TOKEN +
                          "&oauth_version=1.0" +
                          "&screen_name=" + USER_SCREEN_NAME;
    String oauthSignature = "";
    String authorizationHeaderStr = "";
    try {
        String signatureBaseStr = "GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fusers%2Fshow.json&" + URLEncoder.encode(parameterStr, "UTF-8");
        oauthSignature = URLEncoder.encode(computeSignature(signatureBaseStr, TWITTER_SECRET + "&" + USER_SECRET_TOKEN), "UTF-8");
        authorizationHeaderStr = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + TWITTER_KEY +
                                 "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + n +
                                 "\",oauth_signature=\"" + oauthSignature +
                                 "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + t +
                                 "\",oauth_token=\"" + USER_TOKEN +
                                 "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
        System.out.println(signatureBaseStr);
        System.out.println(authorizationHeaderStr);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Create post and receive oauth token
    try {
        String urlStr = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?" + "screen_name=" + USER_SCREEN_NAME;
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeaderStr);

        //Send post
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        //Get post
        int twitterResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer twitterResponse = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            twitterResponse.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(twitterResponse);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the outputstream:

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

I removed that and everything is working fine. I'm honestly not sure why it was there to begin with.